# I want to create a custom URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create a wordpress plugin to create a custom URL. So that when that URL run in browser my PHP code should run.

I am having the below code in my plugin

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_register_route' );

function my_register_route() {
    register_rest_route( 'my-route', 'my-phrase', array(
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'callback' => 'custom_phrase',
                )
            );
}

function custom_phrase() {
    return rest_ensure_response( 'Hello World! This is my first REST API' );
}
```

My plugin got activated in admin side.

But when enter the custom path in browser, its not working

http://localhost/wp/wp-json/my-route/my-phrase
it shows 404 not found.

Please help to find where i have error.

Answer (score 0):

After activating the plugin. Go to WordPress Settings -> Permalinks. Click on save permalinks buttons once. Now the new route will start working.

Comment: no, i have  wordpress installed  in wp folder, so wp is must in url

Comment: no, i have  wordpress installed  in wp folder, so wp is must in url